# Facebook registration form email validation pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, facebook, email-validation

When searching for RegExp patterns to validate an email address in Javascript, I found a pattern that Facebook uses from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8654288).

```
function is_email(a){return /^([\w!.%+\-])+@([\w\-])+(?:\.[\w\-]+)+$/.test(a);}
```

Can someone please explain to me how this pattern works? I understand that it is looking for 'word characters' in three positions along with a '@' character. But a nice explanation will help a lot for me to understand this.

Comment: Here are two websites, that generate more-or-less useful explanations of regex patterns: http://www.regexper.com/ and http://regex101.com/

Comment: Thanks! That works. If you want to write that up as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two websites (that I know of), which generate explanations for regex patterns.

- [regex101.com](http://www.regex101.com) explains the pattern in words
- [regexper.com](http://www.regexper.com) does so graphically

Here is my own explanation for the pattern:

```
^        # anchor the pattern to the beginning of the string; this ensures that
         # there are no undesired characters before the email address, as regex
         # matches might well be substrings otherwise
(        # starts a group (which is unnecessary and incurs overhead)
  [\w!.%+\-]
         # matches a letter, digit, underscore or one of the explicitly mentioned
         # characters (note that the backslash is used to escape the hyphen
         # although that is not required if the hyphen is the last character)
)+       # end group; repeat one or more times
@        # match a literal @
(        # starts another group (again unnecessary and incurs overhead)
  [\w\-] # match a letter, digit, underscore or hyphen
)+       # end group; repeat one or more times
(?:      # starts a non-capturing group (this one is necessary and, because
         # capturing is suppressed, this one does not incur any overhead)
  \.     # match a literal period
  [\w\-] # match a letter, digit, underscore or hyphen
  +      # one or more of those
)+       # end group; repeat one or more times
$        # anchor the pattern to the end of the string; analogously to ^
```

So, this would be a slightly optimised version:

```
/^[\w!.%+\-]+@[\w\-]+(?:\.[\w\-]+)+$/
```